# C# string.GetHashCode() returns non int result

Tags: c#, .net

One of my clients had an app crash and i traced it due to this bug/feature i can't really explain.
The WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode() returns this string: - ?2097695743
Yes, that a minus, a space, a question mark and then the actual hash numbers.

This is the code of a simple console app that show the weird behaviour.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("From String: string name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name");            
    string name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
    Console.WriteLine("name:                            " + name);
    Console.WriteLine("name.GetHashCode().GetType():    " + name.GetHashCode().GetType());
    Console.WriteLine("name.GetHashCode():              " + name.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine("name.GetHashCode().ToString():   " + name.GetHashCode().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Direct");
    Console.WriteLine("WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name:                           " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
    Console.WriteLine("WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode().GetType():   " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode().GetType());
    Console.WriteLine("WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode():             " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode());
    Console.WriteLine("WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode().ToString():  " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This is the text output:

```
From String: string name = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
name:                            COMMARC\tje
name.GetHashCode().GetType():    System.Int32
name.GetHashCode():              - ?2097695743
name.GetHashCode().ToString():   - ?2097695743

Direct
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name:                           COMMARC\tje
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode().GetType():   System.Int32
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode():             - ?2097695743
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.GetHashCode().ToString():  - ?2097695743


Press Enter to continue
```

And this is a picture of the same output:

[image: Weird GetHashCode return value]

My question is: How on earth is this possible?

UPDATE: the problem was with the funky windows settings for negative numbers.

Comment: It is not. I suspect the terminal is bonkers. (The only other possibility is that `int.ToString()` is incorrect, but I doubt that.)

Comment: what if you write the output of the console application to a file using `>` (i.e. `yourApp.exe` > `out.txt`) or use something like `File.WriteAllText()` or `Debug.WriteLine()`?

Comment: It might be culture clash. What does `Name.GetHashCode().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` print?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi I don't have much (really, any) experience with culture stuff ... what sort of culture would prefix a number so?

Comment: Works fine in en-us. I sent you a twitter msg to print out the culture info.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Seems like he's from Slovenia, tried it with sl-SI but no luck

Comment: What version of the framework is this generated on? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Can you add this to your app?
Console.WriteLine("Culture:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("UI Culture:" + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString());

Comment: Works OK in en-GB too, 64 bit OS.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't suck (string/duck) type things - why are you `ToString()`ing a hash code in the first place?

Comment: i'll take all this suggestions and build a new console app for the client. This code works for me fine in any locale but for the client it doesn't. The client is in New Zealand

Comment: @jonathan: what do you mean? in the upper code example i use it to show it behaves the same for direct ToString() call and implicit ToString call behind the scenes. as for the real use i use the hash code to differentiate different users.

Comment: @MladenPrajic the HashCode returned from GetHashCode has an extremely high chance of collisions - it's not used for identifying data uniquely ONLY to allocate items to buckets in HashSets. You are seeing a crash because you are getting duplicate HashCodes. Generate hash codes for all your users and see if you get duplicates.

Comment: You should update the title of this question. GetHashCode() is returning ints just fine, it's just that when you ToString() a negative number with the user's current culture, it returns Unicode characters that the console can't display. (If you output to a file instead, it would be fine.)

Comment: @Jonathan i use them to diff just the users on the same machine. so this is like max 10 users. also for my exact case it doesn't really matter if 2 users do get the same hash code. nothing will break because of it :)

Comment: @MladenPrajic - ToString() is using the locale of the current machine. Check the regional settings in control panel - there is probably a strange character in the number format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If that is the output on the client's computer (but not yours or ours), it's possible the user's machine has specifically configured windows to use "- ?" as the numeric negative symbol. Windows is perfectly willing to let you do that, or any other weird formats.

As a test, I just configured Windows on my machine to use "- ?", and running a simple console app like yours output goofy formatted negative numbers just like your example output. If that's the case on your client's machine, there is nothing wrong with the operation of GetHashCode, it's just an artifact of Windows formatting.

Comment: i'll mark this as answer as it was first. both of you are correct.

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't with GetHashCode(), the problem is with Int32.ToString().  Which is aware of the user's preferences for formatting negative numbers.  Control Panel + Region and Language, Formats tab, Additional Settings button.  Numbers tab, Negative sign symbol setting.  This dialog works a bit differently in earlier versions of Windows, I described the Windows 7 version.